# how to duplicate elements in a list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone know how I can make a list of items such that one row has 1 item, the second row has 2 items, and the third row has 3? You need to duplicate elements in a row. As in the screenshot, one zipper, then on the next row 2 zippers, on the next row 3 zippers.

```
   List<Widget> _convertListItems(List<dynamic> list, bool isSecondList) {
  late List<Widget> children;
   if (isSecondList) {
     children = [
      for (int i in list)
      Row(
        children: [
          for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) _itemPicture(null, i, constants.Assets.lightning),
        ],
      )
      
    ];
   } else {
     children = [
      for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) _item(list[i], i),
    ];
   }

    return children;
  }

  Widget _item(String text, int pos) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        height: 48,
        width: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          border: Border.all(
            color: currentPosition == pos
                ? constants.Colors.white
                : Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: currentPosition == pos
              ? constants.Styles.smallHeavyTimerTextStyleWhite
              : constants.Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite.copyWith(
                  color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemPicture(String? text, int pos, String icon) {
    return SvgPicture.asset(icon, color: currentPosition == pos ? constants.Colors.purpleMain : constants.Colors.green,);
  }
```

Comment: do you want zipper triangle?

Comment: I want to do as in the screenshot, each line will have a different number of elements, it is not necessary that it increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          for (int i in [1, 2, 3])
            Row(children: [
              for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) const Icon(Icons.lightbulb)
            ])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question and added the code. Could you see what the error is, why do I have only 1 element per line?

Comment: @Max You're not making a new Row in the inner loop.

Comment: I updated the question and ran into an error that when the element is centered, the icon is not visible, but the text is visible, what could be the problem?

Comment: @Max i suggest you make a new question for that. Don't keep changing the question whenever you run into a new problem. New problem, new question

Comment: Good. I added a new question, could you look and suggest what could be the problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73233761/why-does-the-central-element-of-the-list-disappear

Comment: Tell me more, how can I get the position of each element in the list? That is, the index under which each row is located.

Answer (score 1):

For Random zipper you may try out below code

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 13,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Row(children: [
              for (var j = 0, i = 0;
                  j <= 10 && i <= Random().nextInt(5);
                  j++, i++)
                const Icon(Icons.airplanemode_on_rounded)
            ]);
          })
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question and added the code. Could you see what the error is, why do I have only 1 element per line?

Comment: I updated the question and ran into an error that when the element is centered, the icon is not visible, but the text is visible, what could be the problem?